# How to make a bitmap font for *nix environments?

Tags: fonts

I have been softy on windows as a font tool to make a bitmap font, it's essentially a modified version of profont I keep using, mostly because the original version is not perfect to me.

I also made a proportional narrower version of profont, which I find extremely readable.

I want to do the same for my Mac and I also want it to work on any *nix, so I'm opting for a way to make it work for *nix first.

I can't understand why fontforge only allows you to make vectorized fonts, I want to make it pixel by pixel...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [gbdfed bitmap font editor](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~mleisher/Software/gbdfed/) to create or modify bitmap fonts for Un*x environments.

If your font is a `.pcf`, you can use [pcf2bdf](http://www.tsg.ne.jp/GANA/S/pcf2bdf/) to convert it to a `.bdf` before hacking on it. There are packages in the Arch AUR and Debian repos for this.

Use [bdftopcf](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/bdftopcf.1.html) to create your final font package and move it to an Xorg font directory, rebuild the font cache and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

FontForge only lets you *define* fonts using vectors, but it allows you to *export* bitmap fonts. Consider it your chance to make the ideal font for both situations.

Comment: vectorized font are gonna take me ages, so that's a no-no.

Comment: The logic in first sentence is unclear, please correct it. (Probably just a missing "not", but I'm not feeling lucky today... :D)

Comment: @Alois: It is accurate. You must "draw" characters using vector shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [fontopia](https://www.gnu.org/software/fontopia/). It is a bitmap font editor for GNU/Linux. It works with PSF, CP, Raw, and PCF fonts. There are many options for editing glyphs, importing and exporting unicode tables, and much more.